# Websphere + MQ client

Tags: ibm-mq

I am getting following error message while connecting to websphere server using MQ client :

```
/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqssslc -x 'X.X.X.10(9110)' -c QMEIGS1.VSER.SVRCONN
QMEIGS1 -k /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMEIGS1/ssl/qmeigs1.arm  -s TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US
```

Error Message :

> LE_DES_SHA_US
>
> Sample AMQSSSLC start
>   Connecting to the default queue manager
>   Using the server connection channel `QMEIGS1.VSER.SVRCONN`
>   on connection name 10.87.205.70(7118).
>   No SSL configuration specified.
>   MQCONNX ended with reason code 2393

We have placed `.arm` file in ssl dir in the path `/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMEIGS1/ssl/qmeigs1.arm`

Please tell me what need to be done to resolve this ?

we are using following Packages on client side :

```
Client version : 8.0.0.4
Client OS : Redhat Linux 6.x 64bit (Non GUI)
```

Packages Installed on client :

```
MQSeriesJRE_vserv-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime_vserv-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesGSKit_vserv-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesClient_vserv-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesSamples_vserv-8.0.0-4.x86_64
```

Regards
Atul

Answer (score 1):

The -k parameter on the client side (the `amqssslc` application) and the queue manager's `ssl` folder should contain a `.kdb` file. You appear to be using a `.arm` file. You should create a Key Database File (KDB) and add the certificate contained in the `.arm` file to that KDB, then rerun using the KDB as the target used by both client and queue manager instead of the `.arm` file.

You can find step-by-step instructions at the following page:
[Running the SSL/TLS sample program](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024430_.htm)

Comment: Hello Morag, Thanks a log for helping out on this. Could you Please tell me how should I bouilt .kdb file from .arm file. Is that same or Webshere server admin should provide the same other than .arm file. Please advice.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the link I provided? Is the .arm file your queue manager certificate? If no, please provide more information in your question and I can update my answer further.